# Can I delete the .hgtags file?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I have forked a project, so I have inherited some tags.

I removed them all via Terminal, which means they are now all prefixed with a bunch of zeros in `.hgtags`.

Is it safe, so to speak, to manually delete the content of this file, or should I just leave it alone as it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can delete .hgtags, and you even could do it before zeroing file